# Uncaught TypeError: Buffer.from is not a function

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, truffle, ganache

I'm writing some smart contracts using solidity and truffle but when I try to migrate my contracts I get the following error:

```
    truffle(develop)> migrate
Uncaught TypeError: Buffer.from is not a function
    at Object.601827 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/index.js:4:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.853983 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/runMigrations.js:1:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.523459 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:5:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.120553 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/index.js:12:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.969203 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/configDefaults.js:27:36)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.200509 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:2:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.503283 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/lib/index.js:30:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.727646 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js:29:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.960306 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-ens/lib/index.js:21:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.529321 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-ens/lib/ENS.js:26:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.688894 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-ens/lib/lib/contentHash.js:31:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.378138 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/content-hash/src/index.js:19:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.576883 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/multicodec/src/index.js:16:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.209550 (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/multicodec/src/varint-table.js:11:1)
    at varintEncode (/home/patricia/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/multicodec/src/util.js:33:1)
```

I tried different versions of node (all >13, any version bellow 13 doesn't compile my contracts). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 TLS

I tried:

```
Truffle v5.5.24 (core: 5.5.24)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v13.14.0
Web3.js v1.7.4

Truffle v5.5.23 (core: 5.5.23)
Ganache v7.3.2
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v15.14.0
Web3.js v1.7.4

Truffle v5.5.24 (core: 5.5.24)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.13.0
Web3.js v1.7.4

Truffle v5.5.24 (core: 5.5.24)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.16.0
Web3.js v1.7.4

Truffle v5.5.24 (core: 5.5.24)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v17.9.1
Web3.js v1.7.4
```

All these different versions output the same error.

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. It seems that npm 8 doesn't work very well with truffle and also it seems that there is a problem in truffle with versions >= 5.4.30.

So the solution was to downgrade npm to version 6 and truffle to version 5.4.29